# Running mvn for pom.xml which placed two levels up - [FATAL] Non-readable POM <path-here>(The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, maven

How can I run mvn (Maven 3.3) for pom.xml which placed in directory two levels up from the current directory (Windows)?
I've tried

> mvn -f ../../pom.xml

But I've got

> [FATAL] Non-readable POM (The system cannot find the file specified)

Could mvn handle pom.xml in parent directories?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I need to call mvn for pom.xml from another project. His pom.xml is placed in another directory two levels up from current directory.

Comment: At first glance this seems to be a strange project architecture ... maybe you are doing an unnecessary complex construction. If a project has subprojects (modules), each level should have a pom and you call mvn on the top-level one.

Answer (score 0):

You must always use the path separators of the OS, so with Windows it should be `mvn -f ..\..\pom.xml`

Comment: With the `tab` you should be able to select the right file. So type `mvn -f ..\..\` and press `tab` a couple of times. You should see the pom.xml, unless you ended up in the wrong directory.